# Wordpress: Why am I getting a 400 from ajaxurl?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to implement basic ajax. I've been following [this tutorial](https://pippinsplugins.com/using-ajax-your-plugin-wordpress-admin/). My JS fires when I click the button but I get a `400` from the ajax url: `POST http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)`

As far as I can tell, I haven't strayed far from the tutorial code. Her is my JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#baa_form').submit(function(){

        var data = {
            action: 'baa_response'
        } 

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
            alert('Hello');
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
function baa_add_menu() {
    global $baa_settings_page;

    $baa_settings_page = add_menu_page( 'Basic Admin Ajax', 'Basic Admin Ajax', 'edit_pages', 'basic-admin-ajax', 'baa_render_settings_page', false, 62.1 );
}

function baa_load_scripts( $hook ) {
    global $baa_settings_page;
    if ( $hook !== $baa_settings_page ) {
        return;
    }
    $path = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/basic-admin-ajax.js';
    wp_enqueue_script( 'basic-admin-ajax', $path, array( 'jquery' ) );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'baa_add_menu' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'baa_load_scripts' );

function baa_render_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <form id="baa_form" method="POST">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="baa_submit_button" id="baa_submit_button" class="button-primary" value="go ajax">
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
}

function baa_response() {
    die( 'I got died' );
}
```

I've had a look inside `admin-ajax.php` and the only reason for returning a `400` that I can see is if I've failed to set an action. `data['action']` is certainly set, unless I'm crazy.

Am I doing anything that's obviously wrong? What could be causing the `400` response?

**update**
To clarify, the JS fires but the request to `admin-ajax.php` receives a `400`. You can see where the tutorial make has implemented similar JS [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1799&v=7pO-FYVZv94). (I haven't added a nonce yet but the video maker had already demonstrated it working without implementing a nonce.)

**edit**
I've updated the PHP to show the plugin's entire PHP file.

**update 2**
I've stripped the JS back to the essentials and followed the top example from [Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). The response is still `400`. Which leads me to believe that it might be something I've overlooked in the php. At the moment, I don't understand why or what it might be.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        'action': 'baa_response'
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

Comment: At what point in the video did you get this code from? Easier to help you if people can watch that part of the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `action`, which will fired on your Ajax request. WordPress can't guess which function related to your Ajax call, and that's why just blocking it( `400 Bad Request` ).

In the php file add this line:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_baa_response', 'baa_response');
```

You may also want to look at the [Ajax in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) documentation.

Comment: If you did not miss add_action, you still might end up with a 400 error (Bad Request). See my answer below ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/54771776/760777 )

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this,

Add this to your **functions.php**,

```
$path = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/basic-admin-ajax.js';
wp_enqueue_script( 'basic-admin-ajax', $path, array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

wp_localize_script( 'basic-admin-ajax', 'action_linklist', array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));

function baa_response() {
   echo "something.....";
   die();
}
```

in your **JS** file,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('#baa_form').submit(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: action_linklist.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data:{'action': 'baa_response'},
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
 });
});
```

Hope this will helps you,

For more information, please visit.

[Using AJAX with wordpress](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/)

[AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: I've updated my PHP so you can see my entire file. The problem isn't that the JS isn't firing, it's that the ajax request is receiving a `400`. After modifying `action_linklist.ajax_url` to `ajaxurl` in the JS, the request still receives a `400`. I see in your example there's no action in the data. Setting `data` to  `{action: 'baa_response }` makes no difference. Also, I have confirmed that `ajaxurl` points to the correct file. This is the path `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` which I believe is correct. I've likely missed something obvious. Can you point out specifically what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I've learned a very important part of the setup.. while I wrote and tested, I was always logged in.. Usually test with incognito, but I was in a rush.. So, if your ajax action is command, you need 2 lines.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_command', 'DoCommand' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_command', 'DoCommand' );
```

nopriv for non-users, removed when user is logged in. Drove me nuts trying to figure this out. not well documented on any example..